# Windows 8 Home & IIS & VS 2012: Can't find virtual directory

Tags: windows, iis, visual-studio-2012

I wonder if this problem is due to the Home Edition of Windows I use.

I have several other development machines (Win 7 Pro) and never had problems with this.

When I open a preexisting ASP.Net project which uses the IIS VS 2012 on Windows 8 Home says it is configured for the use with IIS but doesn't find the web server/directory.

The IIS virtual dir exists though. I have the IIS installed (from the standard Windows feature list). I have setup the web application etc. I can even start websites in the browser with localhost. Only thing is VS 2012 can't find the IIS.

Is there a limitiation in Home?

Comment: That's right, the Home Edition does not support IIS at least on Windows 7 http://forums.iis.net/t/1188608.aspx/1

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have edited my question to calrify I have IIS installed.